# Unable to clear checkbox on same component navigation in Angular 7

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular7, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a filter with checkboxes. The IDs of the elements in the checkbox are stored in an array called activeCheckboxes. I am checking them on ngOnInit(), from what I am getting from query params.

To get the things checked, getting from the query params, I am using this attribute:

```
 [checked]="activeLocation.indexOf('location._id')>-1"
```

Now, when I am resetting the filter, I am simply navigating to the same component with entirely different query-params / no query-params at all. It is working fine. However, the checkboxes are still checked. I have cleared the 'activeCheckboxes' array before navigating. Still, the  same is happening.

Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please try to trigger change detection by arrayVariable = [...arrayVariable]. This is to change the object reference of your array. Simply overwriting array items doesn't trigger angulars change detection and therefore doesn't update your DOM

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I am learning Angular, so, not quite conversant with these intricacies.